# Can't access url but with link it works

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing props through my button and I get redirected to the correct page. When I try to access the page without using the button so like `www.test.com/property/2` my map function is undefined. How can I solve this problem?

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
        <Route exact path="/property/:id" component={SingleProperty} />
        <Route component={ErrorPage} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

```
<Link to={{
    pathname: `/property/${a.Id}`, state: {
        Id: a.Id,
        Title: a.Title,
        Text: a.Text,
        Address: a.Address,
        Rooms: a.Rooms,
        Beds: a.Beds,
        Baths: a.Baths,
        Price: a.Price,
        TypeProperty: a.TypeProperty,
        Date: a.Date
    }
}}>
    <button className="btn btn-sm btn-details text float-right">
        View Details
        </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: In the code you shared, there is no `map` function. It sounds like maybe `SingleProperty` only works if state is passed to component as you do with `Link`. Do you have logic to handle undefined/null values in `SingleProperty`?

Comment: No, I dont have the logic to handle undefined values, but I want to display it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display it even if values are undefined/null? Usually you'd use url params to retrieve values from sort of database or store when the component mounts. You won't be able to pass state values via the URL so if you are wanting this to work via url navigation, you'll need a way to handle undefined values then retrieve the necessary values somehow.

Comment: What I mean is: I make an API call in my ```HomePage``` and I want to send the props to the ```SingleProperty``` to display the data for the particular id. Right now it is only working with the button click but I want to make it possible with the url too. So when I enter ```property/2``` I want to see all the data that I have sent from the ```HomePage```